# Emoji Compat Font Provider not found

Tags: android, kotlin

I've setup EmojiCompat Following the documention I have the files

Import

```
 implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.1.0'
```

`font_certs.xml` - Auto Generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
    </array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
        <item>
            MIIEqDCCA5CgAwIBAgIJANWFuGx9.......
        </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
        <item>
            MIIEQzCCAyugAw....
        </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

`preloaded_fonts.xml` - Auto Generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="preloaded_fonts" translatable="false">
        <item>@font/montserrat_bold_downloadable</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

`montserrat_bold_downloadable` - Auto Generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="name=Montserrat&amp;weight=700"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

And now when calling to initialise this it's failing, but the callback returns null so I dug through to see where it was failing.

```
EmojiCompat.init(
    FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(
        this,
        FontRequest(
            "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
            "com.google.android.gms",
            "name=Montserrat",
            R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
        )
    ).setReplaceAll(true)
)
```

The error that it's throwing internally is;

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: No package found for authority: com.google.android.gms.fonts
```

I can't find anything to do with this issue anywhere.